# Starting activity not specified in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, api, android-activity, manifest

Is it possible to build an appropriate Intent to start one of my activities without specifying it inside AndroidManifest.xml?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, why do you want to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

May be you can get some ideas from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116719/can-i-start-a-new-activity-thats-not-specified-in-the-androidmanifst-xml-file).

Answer (score 6):

No, sorry. All components (activities, services, broadcast receivers, content providers) must be registered in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

No, If you have to call activity then you must have to declare in android manifest file . If you dont declare in it then you get errors . Your application get crashed...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this!
You can using fragments instead of activities and switch between fragments in a main activity